# making a graph well-covered without changing its Shannon capacity

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

This strongly relates to [an earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108851/graphs-with-independence-number-shannon-capacity) of mine.

Let $G$ be a graph, $\alpha(G)$ its independence number and $\Theta(G)$ its Shannon capacity.

**Question:** can one 'add new vertices' to $G$ such that $G\subseteq G'$ becomes an induced subgraph of some [well-covered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-covered_graph) $G'$ with $\alpha(G')=\alpha(G)$ and $\Theta(G') = \Theta(G)$?

If so, this would be a way to 'uniformize' a graph without changing its Shannon capacity. Has anyone considered this question before?

Thanks!

Comment: The new one added vertex should be adjacency with each vertex which can be in a maximum independent set at least.